# How to Set the focus on a keyup event in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, keyup

I created a game in my form and for restarting the game Enter should be pressed.
The problem is when I press Enter to restart the game my form closes or minimizes due to the close button and minimize button that I've made in my form.
What should I do to set the focus on restarting the game and not close or minimizing it?

Comment: If you are using Winforms then your Button has the DialogResult property set to something different than None. Can you tell us if your tag [_forms_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) really means [_WinForms_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms)?

Comment: OK, then it is a duplicate. When you press the ENTER button, the click event  of the current defined AcceptButton on your form, is automatically called. And, if your AcceptButton has a DialogResult property set to anything than None, the form closes as explained in the duplicate